# Repeated and missing number in an array using xor

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

How to find the repeated number and missing number as well using xor? 
For eg: `actual = [1,2,3]` `input_received = [3,2,3]`. Here the missing number is `1` and the repeated number is `3`. I found a quite interesting solution while surfing,

```
int missing_and_repeating(int a[], int n, int size){
    int xor =0;
    int i;
    int x =0 , y =0;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        xor = xor^a[i];
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        xor = xor^i;

    // Get the rightmost bit which is set
    int set_bit_no = xor & ~(xor -1);
    // XOR numbers in two buckets
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        if(a[i]& set_bit_no){
            x = x^a[i];
        }
        else
            y = y^ a[i];
    }
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        if(i & set_bit_no)
            x = x^i;
        else
            y = y^i;
    }

    printf("\n %d %d ", x,y );
}
```

'actual' array is XORed and 'input_received' array is XORed
`set_bit_no` is assigned and both the arrays are split into two halves according to `set_bit_no`.
So again go back to our array and numbers from `1` to `N-1` and `0` to `size` and XOR numbers in two buckets, one buckets contains XOR result of XORing all numbers with given bit set and other bucket contains XOR result of XORing all numbers with given bit reset.

I could not understand what `set_bit_no` is and why they are taking it, and how the array is split according to it. Someone please help me with a short example.

Comment: How you want results to be returned, a set/ or array, containing missing and repeated numbers together?

Comment: result should be an element of array. In this case result should be 1,3

Comment: This is not C++, `xor` is a reserved token there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that pre-condition is that exactly one array element is missing and instead replaced by a duplicate of another element. So, `actual = {a1, a2, ..., an}` and `input_received = {a2, a2,..., an}` (we can always rearrange elements so that `a1` is missing and `a2` is repeated).

So when you xor all elements from both arrays you get `xored = a1 ^ a2`.

Now we have to decompose that number to know `a1` and `a2`. You take one of the non-zero bits (doesn't mater which one, the easiest way is to take the least significant like it's done in the code, and you always have one if `a1 != a2`). This bit is set in only one of numbers `a1` or `a2`. So you xor all numbers which have this bit, and they'll annihilate each other, leaving only `a1` or `a2`, and you xor all other numbers, so the result will be another number - `a2` or `a1` respectively.

It's important to note that this algorithm doesn't tell which of these numbers is missing and which is repeated. This is demonstrated by the following code:

```
int main() {
    int arr1[] = {1, 1};
    missing_and_repeating(arr1, 2, 2);
    int arr2[] = {2, 2};
    missing_and_repeating(arr2, 2, 2);
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
1 2
```

Comment: I really didn't get the term, 'set bits'. Could you please explain it ?

Comment: @user2112700 it means non-zero bits

Comment: Could you please explain with an example, how this split happening with the help of set bits.

Comment: @user2112700 I could, but it will be more useful for you to do it yourself.